# Issues on dividing html part through 'tr' tag using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-crawler

I tried to collect the data from this page (http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_4.php?zone=C&cno=639137&tbl=cyber) using Selenium Python 3.6. What I tried to do is to divide the section into two and collect the data from each part.

The part is like below: 
[image]
[image]

Those items in the two parts are made of 39 'tr' tags. I select 0 to 14th 'tr' tags for the first part and 15th to the end 'tr'tags for the second part. But the first part already called up to the last 'tr' tag. I don't understand why it happened.

Below is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from urllib.parse import quote
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import time


popup_inspection = "http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/mycar/popup/mycarChart_4.php?zone=C&cno=639137&tbl=cyber"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(500, 300)
driver.get(popup_inspection)

soup_inspection = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

count = 0 # for loop count
count_insp = 0 # 누유 및 오작동
count_in = 0 # 골격
count_out = 0 # 외관

insp_tables = soup_inspection.find_all('table', class_=True)

for insp_table in insp_tables[4].find_all('tr'):
    labels = insp_table.find_all('td', class_="center")
    for label in labels[:15]:

        if label.find("input", type="checkbox", checked=True):
            count_out += 1
            print (label.text)
        else:
            print(label.text)
    print("외관 이상 수: ", count_out)

    for label in labels[16:]:
        if label.find("input", type="checkbox", checked=True):
            count_in += 1
            print (label.text)
        else:
            print(label.text)
    print("골격 이상 수: ", count_in)
```

The result I would like to have is like below:

```
<Upper Part>
1 후드 0 0
2 프론트 휀더(좌) 0 0
......
8 트렁크 리드 1 0
Total : 1 0

<Lower Part>
1 프론트 패널
2 크로스 멤버
....
22 리어 패널 1 0
23 트렁크 플로어 0 0 
Total : 1 0
```

Please help me to work this out.

Thanks.

Comment: You should pre-define `count_out = 0` and `count_in = 0` to be able to increase these counters (like `count_out += 1`)

Comment: I forgot that "variable define code"  during copy and paste my code. But, unfortunately, that was not the problem. The problem is the code can't select the correct order of 'tr' tag.